# Which surfing spot has the longest barrels?

Tags: surfing

Is Skeleton Bay - Namibia - the one with the longest barrels of the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Until someone submits proof that beats [this](https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=917562758272322&fref=nf), Skeleton Bay will remain the undisputed winner of that question.